# Обучение грамотному письму: слуховая или зрительная доминанта

Tags: грамотная-речь

Прочитала интересную статью на тему грамотности школьников (датированную  2007 годом), где рассказывается **о программах** обучения русскому языку.

[Трудности с русским языком: психолого-педагогические причины | k-to-k.livejournal.com](http://k-to-k.livejournal.com/135594.html)

Эти  общепринятые программы основаны на так называемом **фонематическом методе,** при котором дети сначала  работают только со звуками,  запоминая слуховой образ слова, делая его звуковую запись (йожык), а потом уже переходят к буквам, то есть к зрительному образу.

В результате такая методика приводит к тотальной безграмотности, к совершенно фантастическим ошибкам, и это понятно: «сначала обучаем детей писать так, как они слышат, а потом пытаемся бороться с тем, чему научили».

Казалось бы, от таких методик надо отказаться и вернуться к проверенным программам 60-70-х годов, но  причиной неуспеваемости  считают не метод, а  невнимательность детей, плохой фонематический слух, дисграфию и т.д. Уйма времени тратится на развитие этого слуха, а результаты  остаются плачевными.

И вопросы:

1) В 2016 году  обучение ведется по этим же программам?

2) Какова современная статистика на эту тему?

(К примеру, в исследовании, проведенном в 2000 году в рамках программы Program for International Student Assessment (PISA), рассматривалось чтение и грамотность 15-летних учащихся из 32 стран (4). Наиболее грамотными были признаны учащиеся Финляндии, Канады, Новой Зеландии, Австралии, Ирландии, Кореи, Великобритании, Японии, Швеции, Австрии (1-10 места). Французские школьники заняли 14-е место, американские — 15-е, испанские — 18-е, итальянские — 20-е, немецкие — 21-е, школьники России оказались на 27-м месте.)

Comment: Интересна методика проверки, так как грамотно писать на французском почти невозможно, а в немецком в те годы проводилась реформа орфографии, которая не могла не сказаться на грамотности.

Comment: Да, интересно,  насколько  вообще эта информация достоверна  и проводятся ли в настоящее время подобные исследования. Вроде бы по-французски даже академики пишут неграмотно,  а как же наши школьники, изучающие французский,  с этим справляются.

Comment: Интересно, где детей обучают по этим программам? Русская орфография основана на трех принципах. Среди них ведущий - морфологический. Фонетический и традиционный принципы не получили широкого распространения. Поэтому для меня странно слышать, что детей обучают, основываясь на фонематическом принципе.

Comment: Можно на форумах родителей посмотреть, например: http://eva.ru/forum/topic-messages.htm?print=true&topicId=2916678
Очень хочу понять, в чем смысл изучения сначала фонетики слова, а потом его написания? - У нас ФГОС учебник Горецкого. - У нас тоже, сама, честно-не понимаю. -

Comment: Раньше этим грешила только Соловейчик (русск.яз. по программе "Гармония" ), а теперь с этими новыми ФГОСами видимо и до программы "Школа России" добрались, т.к. Горецкий именно там  Печально, очень. Видимо цель, чтобы как можно меньше грамотных людей было, т.к. у детей в голове будет каша из того, как говорим и как пишем, прям русский язык для иностранцев. Надо бы научить элементарным правилам правописания  И заумь эта с фонемами-шмонемами детям, в большинстве своем не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не могу сказать по поводу статистики, а вот по поводу обучения в 2017... Насколько я знаю, в начальной школе детей учат читать слова по слогам именно так, как написано: сто - ро - на, сда - ёшь и т. д. Ребёнок должен запомнить "словесный - буквенный облик" слова. Причём слоговое чтение должно быть медленным. Те же дети, которые начинают читать сразу слова целиком, как правило, потом испытывают сложность в написании диктантов: пропускают буквы, делают ошибки на орфографические правила и т.д.
Так что погоня за высокой скоростью чтения у младших школьников оборачивается неграмотностью, как это ни странно.